# using variables to create tasks in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to use variables while creating tasks in snowflake. Below for example:

- **Instead of this:**

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK BEAST_DSC_SBX.DSC_STG.DTCI_DSC_R2O_AVAIL_INCREMENTAL_TRUNCATE
WAREHOUSE = 'BEAST_DSC_ADHOC_WH_SBX' SCHEDULE = '10 MINUTE' WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('BEAST_DSC_SBX.KAFKA.DTCI_DSC_R2O_AVAIL_CHANGES') = True
AS
TRUNCATE TABLE  BEAST_DSC_SBX.DSC_STG.DTCI_DSC_R2O_AVAIL_INCREMENTAL;

- **I want to use this:**

SET STG_SCHEMA_NAME = 'BEAST_DSC_SBX.DSC_STG';
SET KAFKA_SCHEMA_NAME = 'BEAST_DSC_SBX.KAFKA';

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK $STG_SCHEMA_NAME.DTCI_DSC_R2O_AVAIL_INCREMENTAL_TRUNCATE
WAREHOUSE = $WAREHOUSE SCHEDULE = '10 MINUTE' WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA($KAFKA_SCHEMA_NAME'.DTCI_DSC_R2O_AVAIL_CHANGES') = True
AS
TRUNCATE TABLE  $STG_SCHEMA_NAME.DTCI_DSC_R2O_AVAIL_INCREMENTAL;

I am getting errors while executing the above. is it even possible to variablize snowflake tasks? if yes, how?

Comment: You can try wrapping your variables in the create statement with `INDENTIFIER($MY_VARIABLE)`. If that doesn't work, you can use a stored procedure to create them using dynamic names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create the task name with a combination of both text and variable in the Snowflake UI. That doesn't work.

The workaround is to use SnowSQL and use this format:

```
&{<variable>}_<TEXT>
```

Please refer to this KB article as an example: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-variable-when-creating-user-account-in-Snowflake-UI-and-SnowSQL

In the KB article above, we show that you can combine the text and variable in the SnowSQL like so:

```
 create USER &{DIV}_LOCAL_&{ENV}_ADMIN`
    PASSWORD = '&passwd'
    LOGIN_NAME = '&{DIV}_LOCAL_&{ENV}_ADMIN'
    COMMENT = "&DIV &ENV local account admin user"
    DISPLAY_NAME = '&{DIV}_LOCAL_&{ENV}_ADMIN'
    FIRST_NAME = '&{DIV}_LOCAL_&{ENV}_ADMIN'
    LAST_NAME = '&{DIV}_LOCAL_&{ENV}_ADMIN'
    EMAIL = 'test@test.com'
    MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD = TRUE;
```

The example above is to create a user, you can adopt the SQL statement for creating a task.